# How to add custom field in WooCommerce Bookable product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need include a custom field in a WooCommerce Bookalbe product to select a Hotel.I have a taxomony with all hotels , the idea would show this as an option when buying but the extensions "WooCommerce Bookings" don´t use the variable product options. Any idea?

Comment: please give more detail.

Comment: about which field you want to add ??

Comment: and is it effects coast ?